# Concept of clitics

Tags: pronouns, clitics

Are there any differences between pronominal clitics and clitic pronouns? I wonder whether these two terms are interchangeable or not.
Thanks.

Comment: Pronouns are independent words. Clitics fit in the hard to define space between words and morphemes.

Comment: ‘Pronominal clitics’ is ambiguous. It may refer to clitics which are pronominal in nature (i.e., clitic forms of pronouns), or it may refer to clitics which can attach themselves to pronouns. ‘Clitic pronouns’ can only refer to the former of these.